# centering a number under text in a table that is centered to the left

Tags: html, css

I have the table below and in each 'td' I have two divs. One that shows a header and one that shows some number. The table is currently aligned to the left. I want to center the number under the center part of the div above it (taught, hosted, points), but still keep the header info aligned to the left as far as possible. Should I use the 'th' tag for this or some other css?

Here is my table and my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/751thruj/1/)

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointsTags" style="">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Hosted</div>
        <div id="totalHosted" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">6</div>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Attended</div>
        <div id="totalAttended" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">45</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Taught</div>
        <div id="totalTaught" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">344</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Points</div>
        <div id="totalPoints" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">0</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've edited my question a little more to reflect what I am looking for, all answers are incorrect as they are centering the number inside the td, not on the div above it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you need to wrap your two div into one div and give set `display:inline-block` to it. and add `text-align:center` to second div.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointsTags" style="">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
      <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Hosted</div>
        <div id="totalHosted" style="font-size: 25px; text-align:center; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">6</div>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Attended</div>
        <div id="totalAttended" style="font-size: 25px; text-align:center; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">45</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Taught</div>
        <div id="totalTaught" style="font-size: 25px; text-align:center; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">344</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="font-size: 20px;">Points</div>
        <div id="totalPoints" style="font-size: 25px; text-align:center; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">0</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi the best way to do this is .

give the divs a same class like

```
<td>
    <div style="font-size: 20px;" class="sameclass">Hosted</div>
    <div class="centerDivText sameclass" id="totalHosted" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Playfair Display,serif">6</div>

  </td>
```

now you can use css to do this like-`td>:nth-child(2){text-align:center;}`

or
`td>:nth-child(2) .sameclass{text-align:center;}`

try this i hope it will work

if you want to align the upper div text use-

```
td:nth-child(1).sameclass{text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add following lines to the `css` file. No need to create any class.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/751thruj/3/).

```
tr td div:nth-of-type(2){
    text-align:center;
}
```